# When you hard-cut in the VSE, does the current frame end up on the left or right side of the cut?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am going insane trying to eliminate a single frame from a strip.

The procedure I am attempting to use is:

1. Say for example I want to eliminate frame 10.
2. Position the green bar so that frame 11 shows in the preview.
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.
4. On the left-hand-side of the hard cut, position the green bar so that frame 10 shows in the preview.
5. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.
6. <kbd>Delete</kbd> the middle clip.
7. <kbd>G</kbd>-move the right clip to fill the gap.

This is not working. It keeps eliminating the wrong frame. I assume I am making some kind of off-by-one error but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have here 15 frames, each one with a number on it.

When I followed what you did, frame #10 got cut into it's own strip, which can be deleted:

[image: Frame 10]

This are the surrounding frames:

[image: Frame 11]

[image: Frame 9]

I don't know what you are doing wrong, because it works for me.

What this means is that the frame moves to the right of the cut.

Based on this, what you should do is:

1. Move to the frame you want to cut.
2. Enter <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
3. Move 1 frame to the right
4. Enter <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> again
5. Select the middle frame and delete it.
6. Select the next strip and move it 1 frame to the left.

Comment: Thank you; you are correct. It turned out my problem was that the video preview was displaying an image that was not consistent with the actual frame.